# Getting string from database that includes \n, getting \\n instead

Tags: java

Column in Oracle which contains string including `\n`, its returning `\\n` in place of single `\n`. Is there any way to get the exact string that's in the database?

```
//getting fileExposure from oracle db
List<FileExposure> fileExposure =dao.find(FileExposure.class,1);

//geting the string sample_data-->"this is a simple data\n for other features\n"
String sample_data=fileExposure.getSampleData();

//it returning "this is a simple data\\n for other features\\n"
```

Comment: Sounds like the data contains the literal string `\n`, i.e. a backslash followed by the letter `n`, and not a real newline character.

Comment: yes, if i query the column which returns string with \\n why?

Comment: i want to split the string by \n, after reading from DB column.

Comment: A simple fix would be `sample_data.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\")`.

Comment: @Jonny Henly: it wont work, its throwing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing

Comment: Oh that makes sense, use `sample_data.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\\n")` instead.

Comment: thanks henly, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sample_data.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\\n")
```